# fluid simulation effect (like Feed me Oil) in Cocos2D-iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am looking for fluid flowing effect similar in Feed me Oil
in Cocos2D.

Is there any example available? any opensource code?

Edit:

I am looking for something like this -

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1xiVyJ3EOM&feature=player_embedded

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D49KOtfKlF0&feature=player_embedded

Anybody? any idea?

Anybody here??

Answer (score 1):

If you unzip the iBeer's .ipa file then you will see there are lots of images of name foam_000.png,foam_001.png and so on. Similarly for soda. It seems that they are using some `UIImage` animation.